# CInt(Count("") Counting rows in current group in FetchXML report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

I've converted an SSRS report from SQL to FETCHXML that was used by on-premises CRM 2011.

Now the report is using CRM 2013 as the data source.

In the old version of this report we had this expression:

> =String.Format(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(1033), chrw(123)&"0"&chrw(125)&" "&chrw(40)&"Count"&chrw(58)&"
>   "&chrw(123)&"1"&chrw(125)&chrw(41),
>   IIf(IsNothing(Fields!stepname.Value), "Not specified",
>   Fields!stepname.Value),
>   CInt(Count("")).ToString(First(Fields!NumberFormat_0_Precision.Value,
>   "DSNumberAndCurrencyInfo"), Code.GetCultureInfo()))

The following will return the number of rows in the current group; however, when connecting to a CRM online instance (FetchXML), this will not work:

```
CInt(Count("")
```

How can this be accomplished through an expression that is compatible with a FetchXML report?

Answer (score 1):

In your FetchXML can't you use the `aggregate ='count'` with some alias and then use the alias value in your expression?

The article [here](http://crmdm.blogspot.com/2013/09/custom-fetchxml-based-report-in-crm.html) has a report example that uses FetchXml with counts.

> aggregate = 'true' -- This indicates that we are going to use an
>   aggregate function in the fetchxml.
>
> aggregate ='count' -- Here we need the aggregate function count.
>   Because we need count of 'your entity you are wanting to count'.
>
> groupby='true' -- Group by 'your entity you are wanting to count'. And
>   its based on count.